# error echoing form expected comma or semicolon

Tags: php, html

I am trying to echo a form which contains more php. I am getting error message expecting comma or semicolon.

Can anyone help me out?

`echo "<html><body><form action="index.php?tagid="'.$tagid.'" method="post">edit scanned tag's value<input type="text" name="tagvalue"><br><input type="submit" value="<?php $file = fopen("myfile.json","a"); $tagval = json_decode($json); echo $tagval->{'tagid'};  fclose($file);  ?>"></form></body></html>";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your echo contains unescaped qoutes inside. Try this

```
$file = fopen("myfile.json","a"); 
$tagval = json_decode($json); 
fclose($file); 
echo '<html><body><form action="index.php?tagid="'.$tagid.'" method="post">edit scanned tag\'s value<input type="text" name="tagvalue"><br><input type="submit" value="'.$tagval->{'tagid'}.'"></form></body></html>';
```

Or you could write as the following

```
<?php
$file = fopen("myfile.json","a"); 
$tagval = json_decode($json); 
fclose($file); 
?>
<html>
    <body>
      <form action="index.php?tagid="<?php echo $tagid; ?>" method="post">edit scanned tag's value
        <input type="text" name="tagvalue"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $tagval->{'tagid'};?>">
      </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes that gives this error message: "PHP Syntax Check: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''tagid\'}; fclose($file); ?>' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting identifier (T_STRING) in your code on line 1"

Comment: @VirtualTutor Thanks for the info. I have fixed that. Check my answer